# windows at command doesn't work properly

Tags: windows, command-line, at

i am trying to use the `at` command to do a specific one time execution.
assume that i have a batch file at `c:\bat.bat` that contains:

```
%* > d:\out.txt
```

i also have a Java with path registered in my Windows 7 x64.
then i open a CMD prompt as an administrator and try to execute the batch file, like this:

```
c:\bat.bat java
```

above command will execute the batch with a 'java' string as a lone parameter. the 'java' then will be passed into the batch and run with output redirection to a specific file, `d:\out.txt`.
the execution runs properly and the `out.txt` is created and contains some java usage messages.

okay, the problem is, when i am trying to use the `at` command like:

```
at 9:10 c:\bat.bat java
```

the out.txt never created, any idea,.?
note: you can try to put any other program as a parameter.

thanks you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, scheduled tasks run under the SYSTEM account which probably does not have write-access to the location you're trying to write to `d:\out.txt`.

Comment: Will the `/interactive` parameter help in this case?

Comment: no, /interactive doesn't help. i have also see the event log, and found nothing related to the task schedule. i also change the d:\out.txt to c: drive, still not working,.

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
at 9:45 cmd /c "c:\bat.bat java"
```